# Change textBox.text to any key pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, input

I'm trying to when a user presses a key in the textBox the textBox will show the key the user pressed so i can save it as a variable and use it elsewhere.

Right now i have this and this works

```
    private void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            textBox.Text = "A";
        }
    }
```

But it's limited to the A key is there any way to make it any key?

Comment: Did you try this. `textBox.Text = e.Key.ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the KeyEventArgs e.KeyCode to a char.

```
private void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Char ch = (Char)e.KeyCode;
    textBox.Text = ch.ToString();
}
```

EDIT: Forgot this is WPF which doesn't support KeyEventArgs.KeyCode

```
private void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Text = e.Key.ToString();
}
```

> This will give you the things like CapsLock and Shift etc, but, in the
>   case of the alphanumeric keys, it won't be able to tell you the state
>   of shift etc. at the time, so you'll have to figure that out yourself.
>
> The second alternative is to use the TextInput event instead, where
>   e.Text will contain the actual text entered. This will give you the
>   correct character for alphanumeric keys, but it won't give you control
>   characters.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/486967/6138713

Comment: Get the error `KeyEventArgs does not contain a definition for KeyCode`